# Order Stack Overflow search results by votes

Tags: feature-request, search, user-interface

I like the fact that questions get ordered by relevance. Wouldn't it be better to have a sub-filter for sorting by votes?

For example, I would like to see the results of [https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=create video thumbnail](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=create%20video%20thumbnail) ordered by descending number of votes.

Is this possible already? Am I missing something?

Answer (score 1):

On the search results, you have the relevance tab, but there is also a tab for "votes". However, thanks to the behemoths like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/194812/list-of-freely-available-programming-books) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1711/what-is-the-single-most-influential-book-every-programmer-should-read) which happen to contain "video" at random points of their plethora of answers, using that with a [plain search entry](https://stackoverflow.com/search?tab=votes&q=create%20video%20thumbnail) does not yield very useful results.

Try [prefacing each term with "body:" such as `body:create body:video body:thumbnail`](https://stackoverflow.com/search?tab=votes&q=body%3acreate%20body%3avideo%20body%3athumbnail) or [prefacing each term with "+" such as `+create +video +thumbnail`](https://stackoverflow.com/search?tab=votes&q=%2bcreate%20%2bvideo%20%2bthumbnail). The former draws from the same pool of results as the plain search, but it specifically looks through answers as well and orders by the actual post's vote score instead of just the question's. The latter only returns results that have all 3 terms.